# Why can my Button be clicked even when it is disabled?

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a SignUpActivity with a couple of `EditText`s and a `Button` in it.
Provided all text fields are not empty, the button is enabled thanks to some `TextWatcher`s.

Additionally, the last `EditText` has an `OnEditorActionListener` attached so when I click "Done" on the soft keyboard, the button is clicked and the sign up is performed, like this:

```
@OnEditorAction(R.id.sign_up_password_field)
protected boolean onPasswordFieldEditorAction(int actionId) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Click button
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am not using `.callOnClick()` because it:

> Directly call any attached OnClickListener.  Unlike {@link #performClick()}, this only calls the listener, and does not do any associated clicking actions like reporting an accessibility event.

, as stated in the documentation. However, I thought that `.performClick()` would fit my purpose since it:

> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined.  Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

**My problem:** both `.performClick()` and `.callOnClick()` call the listener regardless the button is enable or disable.

**My question:** How exactly thees method work? and, is there I a way to achieve this without checking `buttonSignUp.isEnabled()`??

Comment: No. There's not. Enabling/disabling a button is for the User input, you still can perform clicks with these functions

Comment: A button being disabled does not mean that it's onclick implementation is removed or otherwise disabled. At least as of my understanding, whether a button is enabled or not is purely a UI concept. My guess is that you will have to check if it is enabled or not. You could however do this directly within the onclick listener to prevent having to do the check at multiple places in your code.

Comment: I know with these functions is not possible but that's precisely my poing..with espresso for instance this would be possible, you can perform an UI click programmatically, that depends on the enabled/disabled state...